# Does Required attribute works for properties Excluded from binding in Model while passing to Actionresult in Asp.Net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is my model:

```
public class JQueryDataTableParamModel
{
     /// <summary>
     /// Request sequence number sent by DataTable, same value must be returned in response
     /// </summary>   
     [Required]
     public string sEcho { get; set; }

     /// <summary>
     /// Text used for filtering
     /// </summary>
     [Required]
     public string sSearch { get; set; }
}
```

This is my ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult VolumeOverviewHandler([Bind(Include = "sEcho")]JQueryDataTableParamModel param)
```

My question is does the Required attribute on 2nd property going to create issues in this case?

Comment: Can you mark my answer as correct to help other people please and thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice question, the ***Bind*** attribute will improve the performance by only bind properties which you needed.

You can check if this will cause any problem by using the **ModelState** entity.

Inside your controller, the first thing you do is checking the **ModelState** use the following instruction:

```
if(!ModelState.IsValid){ throw new someException(); or return BadRequest("Model Is Not Valid");}
```

If you're **ModelState** is valid. You can consider that there are no problems, and proceed with whatever you want to do.